# Issues forming and executing if statements

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, parse-platform

I am having issues forming and executing my if statements below. My problem is as follow - how do I set up a condition through parse that returns the list of users based on the gender the user has selected, and based on the gender that the user is looking for. In other words, I would want to return the opposite sex of the user, unless they are looking for the same sex.

I have tried to achieve this using a series of if statements, but have encountered issues along with the way such as the following error:

```
The operator && is undefined for the argument type(s) ParseQuery<ParseUser>, boolean
```

Below is the if statement code

```
   if(query.whereEqualTo("Looking_Gender","Male") != null)
                   query.whereNotEqualTo("Looking_Gender","Male");
                if(query.whereEqualTo("Looking_Gender","Female") != null)
                       query.whereNotEqualTo("Looking_Gender","Female");

                if(query.whereEqualTo("Looking_Gender","Female") && (query.whereEqualTo("Gender","Female") != null)
                       query.whereEqualTo("Looking_Gender","Female");
                else
                    query.whereEqualTo("Looking_Gender","Female");


                if(query.whereEqualTo("Looking_Gender","Male") && (query.whereEqualTo("Gender","Male") != null)
                           query.whereEqualTo("Looking_Gender","Male");
                else
                    query.whereEqualTo("Looking_Gender","Female");
```

Below is my entire code

```
public class MatchingActivity extends Activity {

     private String currentUserId;
        private ArrayAdapter<String> namesArrayAdapter;
        private ArrayList<String> names;
        private ListView usersListView;
        private Button logoutButton;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.matching);

            logoutButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logoutButton);
            logoutButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    ParseUser.logOut();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

            setConversationsList();
        }

        private void setConversationsList() {
            currentUserId = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId();
            names = new ArrayList<String>();
           String userActivitySelectionName = null;


            ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
               query.whereNotEqualTo("objectId", currentUserId);
               query.whereEqualTo("ActivityName",userActivitySelectionName);

               if(query.whereEqualTo("Looking_Gender","Male") != null)
                   query.whereNotEqualTo("Looking_Gender","Male");
                if(query.whereEqualTo("Looking_Gender","Female") != null)
                       query.whereNotEqualTo("Looking_Gender","Female");

                if(query.whereEqualTo("Looking_Gender","Female") && query.whereEqualTo("Gender","Female") != null)
                       query.whereEqualTo("Looking_Gender","Female");
                else
                    query.whereEqualTo("Looking_Gender","Female");


                if(query.whereEqualTo("Looking_Gender","Male") && query.whereEqualTo("Gender","Male") != null)
                           query.whereEqualTo("Looking_Gender","Male");
                else
                    query.whereEqualTo("Looking_Gender","Female");

            query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
                public void done(List<ParseUser> userList, ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        for (int i=0; i<userList.size(); i++) {
                            names.add(userList.get(i).getUsername().toString());
                        }

                        usersListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.usersListView);
                        namesArrayAdapter =
                            new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                                R.layout.user_list_item, names);
                        usersListView.setAdapter(namesArrayAdapter);

                        usersListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int i, long l) {
                                openConversation(names, i);
                            }
                        });

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error loading user list",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        public void openConversation(ArrayList<String> names, int pos) {
            ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
            query.whereEqualTo("username", names.get(pos));
            query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
               public void done(List<ParseUser> user, ParseException e) {
                   if (e == null) {
                       Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MessagingActivity.class);
                       intent.putExtra("RECIPIENT_ID", user.get(0).getObjectId());
                       startActivity(intent);
                   } else {
                       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                           "Error finding that user",
                               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   }
               }
            });
        }
    }
```

If you could assist me in anyway, please let me know. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update**
Based around the suggestions I have kindly received, below is the code. I am not sure if this makes logical sense as it doesn't seem to work now. I have added my comments in between

```
 currentUserId = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId();
ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
               //It cannot return the current user for you can't possibly match yourself
               query.whereNotEqualTo("objectId", currentUserId);
               // If current user is a male, is looking for a female, than return female              
             query.whereEqualTo("Gender","Male").whereEqualTo("Looking_Gender","Female");
              // If current user is looking for a female, looking for a male than return male
             query.whereEqualTo("Gender","Female").whereEqualTo("Looking_Gender","Female");

            //if current user is a female, and is looking for a female than return female   
             query.whereEqualTo("Looking_Gender","Female").whereEqualTo("Gender","Female");
            //if current user is a male and is looking for a male, than return a male
             query.whereEqualTo("Looking_Gender","Male").whereEqualTo("Gender","Male");
```

Anyhelp would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I don't think you are following proper syntax for control statements. Have a look at this documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html

Comment: You are right. I don't think I had the right syntax. Hence, i have updated my code under the update section of my initial post. Kindly take a look it.

Answer (score 2):

It's because `whereEqualTo` returns a query, not a boolean.  You should be chaining these queries rather than using them as `if` statements.  Somewhat like so:

```
query.whereEqualTo("Looking_Gender","Female").whereEqualTo("Gender","Female")
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response, and the clarification. I have updated the code based around my suggestion under update of my initial post. It would be greatly helpful if you could look into it, as I am experiencing minor issues here and there.

Comment: You need to specify what "it doesn't work" means, still.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (query.whereEqualTo("Looking_Gender","Female") && (query.whereEqualTo("Gender","Female") != null)
```

This checks to see what `query.whereEqualTo("Looking_Gender","Female")` is first. What is it? Is it a boolean? If not, it needs to be compared to something to yield a boolean.

I believe it's a `ParseQuery<ParseUser>` although you haven't told us.

Overall you need this syntax:

```
if (boolean_expression && boolean_expression)
```

and the left side of && in the line of code above is not a boolean expression. You have the mistake twice.

You probably want to compare it to null, either == or !=.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response, and suggestions.Indeed, I am using ParseQuery to achieve this. I have updated my code under the update section of my initial post. I still have minor issues to resolved. Kindly take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

You're misunderstanding the way a Parse query works. Each `whereEqualTo()` function is like adding an AND expression.

You end up searching for users where "Gender" is equal to "Male" and also equal to "Female", which of course doesn't work since it can't be equal to both strings at once. Same with your checks against "Looking_Gender".

As per my answer to your other question, you need to read the values out for the current user and then use those values in your `whereEqualTo()` expressions, e.g.:

```
// find users with Gender equal to what the current user is looking for
query.whereEqualTo("Gender", currentUserLookingGender);
// and that are looking for people of the current user's gender
query.whereEqualTo("Looking_Gender", currentUserGender);
```